# How to use headings of various size - Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to create this effect in Microsoft Word:

[image]

I currently have the text on both ends, but I don't know how to create the larger text in the center without messing up vertical alignment for the text on the outer ends.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use a table with 1 row and 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can insert a table in Word with three columns, insert the content for example：

[image]
Then select the table, under Table Tools, select Design, select Table Grid style to remove grid:
[image]